# Tomcat 7 file write permission on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, permissions

I have developed a jax-rs web service with jersey and tomcat 7. Now I put the war-file to my remote server, running with ubuntu. My web service have an upload function for images, and the images are stored to a given directory (path is configured by a config-file). My problem is, the web service throws an exception "permission denied" if it try to write the file (seen in log file).

What permissions or config properties do I must set to give my web service writing permission?

My desire is, to grant the permission for a specific user on the server. I have for each servlet an own user created (cause different projects), and I wish to only grant the permission for this folder to the user.

What I tried is to set the permission of the target folder to 777 with `chmod` and set the owner of the directory (and all sub dirs) to `tomcat7`. But it didn't work.

Comment: you need to grant access to ALL of the parent folders as well. that doesn't mean "write" perms, but the relevant user account(s) MUST be able to at at least traverse those parent directories. otherwise it's the equivalent of having a "free take one" display inside a locked bank vault. you can take all you want, but you can't ever reach it.

Comment: @MarcB nice compare :) so, when my target folder is the home directory of the user, I need to set the permission to write for the "tomcat7" user to the "home" folder to? (sry for my bad english)

Comment: unless you're changing UIDs in your codebase and assuming the ID of the user whose dir you're writing into, yes, the tomcat user MUST have at least traverse permissions on the folders. you only need "write" on the immediate folder the file's going into, e.g. `/home(traverse)/fred(traverse)/data(traverse)/finaldir(write)/somefile(write)`

Comment: Okay thank you for that information. But how can I set the owner / executer of a single servlet in tomcat? (to make sure the servlet get only the rights for the project user)

Comment: no idea on that. never done any tomcat stuff.